# Exporting footnotes to Beamer places them too low on the frame

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode, beamer

How do I define the space allocated to the footnotes in an Org file that is intended to be exported as a Beamer presentation? The problematic result is shown below:

[image]

The relevant bit of Org file looks like this:

```
#+STARTUP: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [bigger]
#+BEAMER_FRAME_LEVEL: 2
#+COLUMNS: %40ITEM %10BEAMER_env(Env) %9BEAMER_envargs(Env Args) %4BEAMER_col(Col) %10BEAMER_extra(Extra)

* Role of Org-Babel

** Overview                                                         :B_verse:
   :PROPERTIES:
   :BEAMER_env: verse
   :END:
   =org-babel= is a facility that provides inline code evaluation,
   highlighting and tangling[fn:1: Tangling and untangling is the
   process employed in literate programming for hiding and displaying
   code blocks.].
```

PS. Of course *literate* programming.

Comment: You should provide the code that you wrote.

Comment: @NicolasDudebout the code is *extremely* straight-forward really. Just replace the `1` with `[fn:1: blah-blah]` and you have it.

Comment: You should put it in the question so that we can copy paste it in `foo.org` and work with it. You are more likely to get an answer that way.

Comment: @NicolasDudebout OK, here, I've updated the question.

Comment: To quote `beameruserguide`: _Using footnotes is usually not a good idea. They disrupt the flow of reading._

Comment: @MartinSchröder you might want to quote that to Wikipedia ;) But seriously, my opinion on this is that whether to use a feature should be the user's concern, and it should be the developer's concern to provide it. Developers don't need to tell users what they should want. That sounds like a poorly concealed tactics of blaming the users for the faults in the software (I know that, because I've done that too :P)

Comment: @wvxvw: A presentation is neither an article nor a handout.

Comment: @MartinSchröder again, this is just a matter of taste. Perhaps, a particular usage scenario. There is no reason why some common typographic approaches should be banned from usage. The thing you quote is strictly subjective. There is no such universal rule. That's just the guide author's personal opinion. Having graduated from a faculty of book design, I think I can judge for myself whether to take such advises at the face value ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following option in your header:

```
#+LaTeX_HEADER:\addtobeamertemplate{footnote}{}{\vspace{2ex}}
```

Comment: This would also add space between two footnotes. Is there anyway to only add space after the last footnote?